# Durandal: Ajax get request displays blank page rather than my customize spinning

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, durandal

**Problem/Unwanted Result:** In addition to displaying my composed "spinning icon", it displays a blank page while the request is in process and then the blank page is gone after it is done.

**Purpose:** I am trying to display a list of events as Json from a server asynchronously. When it is in progress, I want to display my customized spinning icon.

**How**: I have *event.hmtl* and *event.js*. I use "durandal compose" to compose either "view of event list from the server" or "the spinning icon". 
1- When I click on a refresh button, it will call "refreshEvent" function to compose "spinning icon" while processing. 
2- The refreshEvent will do ajax call to server to get the event list.
3- After it is done, I bind the result to observable data and compose "event list view" instead.

**Event.html:**

```
     <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11">
                    <h1>Upcoming events</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                    <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" data-bind="click: refreshEvent"></span>
                </div>

            </div>

    <div class="h-events row">
        <div data-bind="compose: { view: upcoming_event activationData: $root }"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**Event.js:**

```
define('services/logger', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/activator', 'plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'services/errorhandler', 'jquery'],
    function (logger, system, activator, router, app, errorhandler, $) {


        var view = {
            progress: 'partials/_progress.html',
            upcoming_event: 'partials/_upcoming-event.html',
        };

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        events: ko.observable(),
        upcoming_event: ko.observable(view.progress),
        feed_view: ko.observable(view.progress),
        refreshEvent: refreshEvent,
        even_detail : 
            {
                description: ko.observable(),
                title: ko.observable(),
                date: ko.observable(),
                month: ko.observable(),
                time: ko.observable(),
                name: ko.observable().extend({
                    required: { message: 'Name is required' },
                    minLength: { message: 'Name must be at least 3 characters', params: 3 }

                }),
                team_name: ko.observable().extend({
                    required: { message: 'Team name is required' },
                    minLength: { message: 'Team name must be at least 3 characters', params: 3 }

                }),
                email: ko.observable().extend(
                    {
                        required: { message: 'Email is required' },
                        email: { message: 'Email must be in correct format e.g. example@domain.com' }
                    }),
                phone: ko.observable().extend({
                    required: { message: 'Phone number is required' },
                    number: { message: 'Phone must be number and no spaces' },
                    minLength: { message: 'Phone number must be at least 9 digits', params: 9 }

                }),
                message: ko.observable(),
                event_id: "",
                event_detail_view: ko.observable(),
                old_event_view : "",

            }
    };

    vm.errors = ko.validation.group(vm, { deep: true, observable: false, live: false });


    function refreshEvent() {
        vm.upcoming_event(view.progress); //display spinning icon

        Q.when($.ajax({
                url: '/breeze/feed/FeedAndEvent',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'

            })).then(function (result) {

            vm.upcoming_event(result); //display
            vm.upcoming_event(view.upcoming_event);

        }).fail(errorhandler);

    }

    function activate() {

    }

    return vm;
});
```

Comment: Have you looked and seen how the hottowel example is setup to do this?  The main razor view delivers the spinner page as a partial view and then that is replaced by the durandal view after it downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I can see what you are trying to do. I am not sure it is possible to switch out just the view portion of the compose binding and expect it to update. You may need to compose directly to an observable that contains a reference to the desired viewmodel that you wish to display at any point in time.

However, try fixing this first. There is a mistake in the compose binding:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { view: upcoming_event activationData: $root }"></div>

<!-- Should have a comma after upcoming_event -->
<div data-bind="compose: { view: upcoming_event, activationData: $root }"></div>
```